# No real acceleration with pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, c99

I am trying to implement the multithreaded version of the Monte-Carlo algorithm. Here is my code:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_THREADS 12
#define MAX_DOTS 10000000

double sum = 0.0;
sem_t sem;

void reset() {
    sum = 0.0;
}

void* check_dot(void* _iterations) {
    int* iterations = (int*)_iterations;
    for(int i = 0; i < *iterations; ++i) {
        double x = (double)(rand() % 314) / 100;
        double y = (double)(rand() % 100) / 100;
        if(y <= sin(x)) {
            sem_wait(&sem);
            sum += x * y;
            sem_post(&sem);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void* check_dots_advanced(void* _iterations) {
    int* iterations = (int*)_iterations;
    double* res = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
    for(int i = 0; i < *iterations; ++i) {
        double x = (double)(rand() % 314) / 100;
        double y = (double)(rand() % 100) / 100;
        if(y <= sin(x)) *res += x * y;
    }
    pthread_exit((void*)res);
}

double run(int threads_num, bool advanced) {
    if(!advanced) sem_init(&sem, 0, 1);
    struct timespec begin, end;
    double elapsed;
    pthread_t threads[threads_num];
    int iters = MAX_DOTS / threads_num;
    for(int i = 0; i < threads_num; ++i) {
        if(!advanced) pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, &check_dot, (void*)&iters);
        else pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, &check_dots_advanced, (void*)&iters);
    }
    if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &begin) == -1) {
        perror("Unable to get time");
        exit(-1);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < threads_num; ++i) {
        if(!advanced) pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
        else {
            void* tmp;
            pthread_join(threads[i], &tmp);
            sum += *((double*)tmp);
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
    if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end) == -1) {
        perror("Unable to get time");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if(!advanced) sem_destroy(&sem);
    elapsed = end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec;
    elapsed += (end.tv_nsec - begin.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
    return elapsed;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    bool advanced = false;
    char* filename = NULL;
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        if(strcmp(argv[i], "-o") == 0 && argc > i + 1) {
            filename = argv[i + 1];
            ++i;
        }
        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "-a") == 0 || strcmp(argv[i], "--advanced") == 0) {
            advanced = true;
        }
    }
    if(!filename) {
        fprintf(stderr, "You should provide the name of the output file.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    FILE* fd = fopen(filename, "w");
    if(!fd) {
        perror("Unable to open file");
        exit(-1);
    }
    srand(time(NULL));
    double worst_time = run(1, advanced);
    double result = (3.14 / MAX_DOTS) * sum;
    reset();
    fprintf(fd, "Result: %f\n", result); 
    for(int i = 2; i <= MAX_THREADS; ++i) {
        double time = run(i, advanced);
        double accel = time / worst_time;
        fprintf(fd, "%d:%f\n", i, accel);
        reset();
    }
    fclose(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

However, I can't see any real acceleration with increasing the number of threads (and it does not matter what check_dot() function I am using). I have tried to execute this code on my laptop with Intel Core i7-3517u (*lscpu* says that it has 4 independent CPUs) and it looks like the number of threads not really influences the execution time of my program:

```
Number of threads: 1, working time: 0.847277 s
Number of threads: 2, working time: 3.133838 s
Number of threads: 3, working time: 2.331216 s
Number of threads: 4, working time: 3.011819 s
Number of threads: 5, working time: 3.086003 s
Number of threads: 6, working time: 3.118296 s
Number of threads: 7, working time: 3.058180 s
Number of threads: 8, working time: 3.114867 s
Number of threads: 9, working time: 3.179515 s
Number of threads: 10, working time: 3.025266 s
Number of threads: 11, working time: 3.142141 s
Number of threads: 12, working time: 3.064318 s
```

I supposed that it should be some kind of linear dependence between the execution time and number of working threads for at least four first values (the more threads are working the less is execution time), but here I have pretty equal time values. Is it a real problem in my code or I am too demanding?

Comment: Multi-threading is very expensive. It's only worth it if you have profound algorithmic and mathematical reasons to believe that concurrency can speed up your processing to such an extent that the benefits outweigh the cost.

Comment: Core i7-3517u is dual core (with hyper-threading); which means that for 2 threads you get 2 cores busy, and with 4 threads you get "2 threads per core" sharing the core's resources. For anything more than 4 threads it's a pure waste of time (the only thing you gain is thread switching overhead).

Comment: @EOF, I will be grateful if you explain why access to `sum` is unsynchronized. I use semaphore here, don't I?

Comment: @kasom: True, I didn't see that. One day I'll learn to read before commenting. Of course, this also answers your question in turn: You almost certainly have a horribly contended semaphore.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to collect the timing / scaling measurements that you would desire with two changes to your code.

First, [rand()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand) is not thread safe.  Replacing the calls with calls to rand_r(seed) in the advanced check_dots showed continual scaling as threads increased.  I think rand might have an internal lock that is serializing execution and preventing any speedup.  This change alone shows some scaling, from 1.23s -> 0.55 sec (5 threads).

Second, I introduced barriers around the core execution region so that the cost of serially creating/joining threads and the malloc calls is not included.  The core execution region shows good scaling, from 1.23sec -> 0.18sec (8 threads).

Code was compiled with `gcc -O3 -pthread mcp.c -std=c11 -lm`, run on Intel E3-1240 v5 (4 cores, HT), Linux 3.19.0-68-generic.  Single measurements reported.

```
pthread_barrier_t bar;

void* check_dots_advanced(void* _iterations) {
    int* iterations = (int*)_iterations;
    double* res = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
    sem_wait(&sem);
    unsigned int seed = rand();
    sem_post(&sem);
    pthread_barrier_wait(&bar);
    for(int i = 0; i < *iterations; ++i) {
        double x = (double)(rand_r(&seed) % 314) / 100;
        double y = (double)(rand_r(&seed) % 100) / 100;
        if(y <= sin(x)) *res += x * y;
    }
    pthread_barrier_wait(&bar);
    pthread_exit((void*)res);
}

double run(int threads_num, bool advanced) {
    sem_init(&sem, 0, 1);
    struct timespec begin, end;
    double elapsed;
    pthread_t threads[threads_num];
    int iters = MAX_DOTS / threads_num;
    pthread_barrier_init(&bar, NULL, threads_num + 1); // barrier init
    for(int i = 0; i < threads_num; ++i) {
        if(!advanced) pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, &check_dot, (void*)&iters);
        else pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, &check_dots_advanced, (void*)&iters);
    }
    pthread_barrier_wait(&bar); // wait until threads are ready
    if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &begin) == -1) { // begin time
        perror("Unable to get time");
        exit(-1);
    }

     pthread_barrier_wait(&bar); // wait until threads finish
     if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end) == -1) { // end time
        perror("Unable to get time");
        exit(-1);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < threads_num; ++i) {
        if(!advanced) pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
        else {
            void* tmp;
            pthread_join(threads[i], &tmp);
            sum += *((double*)tmp);
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
    pthread_barrier_destroy(&bar);
```

Comment: I find it a bit baffling that you would (correctly!) point out `rand()`s thread-unsafety, then use it in `check_dots_advanced()` without synchronization.

Comment: I used it as a quick way to seed rand_r().  I needed a value to seed each thread, so for the purposes of determining / demonstrating the basic scalability issue, it was a simpler change.  I've edited the code to use the semaphore to protect this single call to rand().

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing is that the internal state of `rand()` is a shared resource between all threads, so the threads are going to serialise on access to `rand()`.

You need to use a pseudo-random number generator with per-thread state - the `rand_r()` function (although marked obsolete in the latest version of POSIX) can be used as such.  For serious work you would be best off importing the implementation of some specific PRNG algorithm such as Mersenne Twister.